Issues with Managing the Sliding Window in a JavaScript Function - Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters
I've been working on a JavaScript function to calculate the length of the longest substring without repeating characters. I encountered a couple of issues that I'm hoping to get some clarity on:
Using if vs. while for Duplicate Detection:
My initial implementation used an if statement to check for duplicates (if(set.has(s[right]))). However, I noticed it doesn't work as expected, and replacing if with while (while(set.has(s[right]))) seems to solve the issue. Why does the while loop work correctly here instead of if?
Order of Operations with Increment and Deletion:
In my function, when a duplicate is detected, I tried to delete the character from the set immediately after incrementing the left pointer (left++ followed by set.delete(s[left])). This approach doesn't seem to work properly. What's the correct order of operations in this scenario to maintain the integrity of the sliding window?
function subs(s) {
       const set = new Set();
       let left = 0;
       let total = 0;
       for(let right = 0; right< s.length; right++) {
           if(set.has(s[right])){
            set.delete(s[left]);
            left++;
          }
          set.add(s[right]);
          total = Math.max(total, right - left + 1);
       }
       return total;
    }







function subs(s) {
    const set = new Set();
    let left = 0;
    let total = 0;
    for (let right = 0; right < s.length; right++) {
        while (set.has(s[right])) {
            set.delete(s[left]);
            left++;
        }
        set.add(s[right]);
        total = Math.max(total, right - left + 1);
    }
    return total;
}
console.log(subs("abcabcbb") === 3, "Test Case 1 Failed");
console.log(subs("bbbbb") === 1, "Test Case 2 Failed");
console.log(subs("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") === 26, "Test Case 3 Failed");




This is merely what the OP posted and described, it does not answer any of the questions the OP stated and it's completely unclear if the subs function even works correctly because we don't know what the expected result is for each call. I highly doubt the function is for counting unique characters in a string (that's what your (failing?) tests suggest), because this could be achieved a lot easier: function countUniqueChars(s) { return new Set(s.split('')).size; }

You’re right; the function isn't just counting unique characters. It's finding the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.
